# Getting the latest value in a time range or null

Tags: apache-spark, f#, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge data set e.g.

```
| Date       | ID | Value |
+------------+----+-------+
| 10-10-2020 | 1  | 1     |
| 10-11-2020 | 1  | 2     |
| 10-12-2020 | 1  | 3     |
| 10-13-2020 | 1  | 4     |
| 10-10-2020 | 2  | 5     |
| 10-11-2020 | 2  | 6     |
| 10-12-2020 | 2  | 7     |
| 10-09-2020 | 3  | 8     |
| 10-08-2020 | 4  | 9     |
```

As you can see this example contains of 4 IDs within different date ranges.

I have a special logic, which calculates some derived values with `RangeBetween` function. Let's assume it is a simple `sum` over the defined time range.

What I need to do is to generate such a result (explained below):

```
| ID | Value sum (last 2 days) | Value sum (last 4 days) | Value sum (prev 2 days) | Value sum (prev 4 days) | Result (2 days) | Result (4 days) |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 7 (3+4)                 | 10 (1+2+3+4)            | 5 (3+2)                 | 6 (3+2+1)               | 7               | 10              |
| 2  | 7                       | 18 (5+6+7)              | 11 (5+6)                | 11 (5+6)                | 7               | 18              |
| 3  | null                    | null                    | null                    | 8                       | null            | 0               |
//exclude | 4  | null          | null                    | null                    | null                    | null            | null            |
```

This example assumes that `today` is `10-13-2020`.
For each Id I need to get a sum of the value in 2 ranges: 2 and 4 days

```
1. the table contains 2 calculations for the same ranges starting from now and the day before (columns last and prev X days)
2. if all values exist in a range - simply result the sum of the range (example with ID = 1)
3. if some of values are not specified in a range assume it is zero (example with ID = 2)
4. if values do not exist in the defined range, but there is at least 1 value in the range with the day before - assume there was a sum yesterday, but no such today - set it to zero (example #3)
5. if no value values in the range and the day before - do not include in the result set (example #4)
```

Right now I have a code:

```
let last2Days =
    Window
        .PartitionBy('ID')
        .OrderBy(Functions.Col('Date').Cast("timestamp").Cast("long"))
        .RangeBetween(-1, 0)

let prev2Days =
    Window
        .PartitionBy('ID')
        .OrderBy(Functions.Col('Date').Cast("timestamp").Cast("long"))
        .RangeBetween(-2, -1)

df
    .WithColumn('last2daysSum', Functions.Sum('value').Over(last2Days))
    .WithColumn('prev2daysSum', Functions.Sum('value').Over(last4Days))
    .WithColumn('result2Days', Functions.Col('last2daysSum'))
    .Where(Functions.Col('Date').EqualTo(Functions.Lit('10-13-2020')))
```

This works for example #1 (when result is taken from `last2daysSum`)

```
1. is there a simple way to get a proper result for #2 (the latest record within defined time range)?
2. combine the previous question and condition `if last = null && prev != null then 0 else if last = null && prev = null then null else last` - example #3?
3. how to exclude records as per example #4?
```

Is that possible to solve it with no reshuffling?

Answer (score 1):

For Question #1 If you only want to calculate for one specific date then a `groupBy` and `agg` is simpler and should execute faster. The trick is to use `when` inside aggregate functions like `sum`.

For Questions #2 and #3 you can coalesce to zero and filter out fully null rows before that. If you need to filter for a broader range than you want to display (so include rows that had values days before but do not now) you can add an extra calculation for the longer period a drop that after filtering. See below for code example.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(
  ("2020-10-10", 1, 1),
  ("2020-10-11", 1, 2),
  ("2020-10-12", 1, 3),
  ("2020-10-13", 1, 4),
  ("2020-10-10", 2, 5),
  ("2020-10-11", 2, 6),
  ("2020-10-12", 2, 7),
  ("2020-10-09", 3, 8),
  ("2020-10-08", 4, 9)
).toDF("Date", "ID", "Value").withColumn("Date", to_date($"Date"))

def sumLastNDays(now: java.sql.Timestamp, start: Int, end: Int = 0) = 
  sum(when($"Date".between(date_sub(lit(now), start-1), date_sub(lit(now), end)), $"Value"))

val now = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2020-10-13 00:00:00")

data
  .groupBy($"ID")
  .agg(
    sumLastNDays(now, 2).as("last2DaysSum"),
    sumLastNDays(now, 4).as("last4DaysSum"),
    sumLastNDays(now, 4, 2).as("prev2DaysSum"),
    sumLastNDays(now, 5).as("last5DaysSum")
  )
  .filter($"last5DaysSum".isNotNull)
  .drop($"last5DaysSum")
  .withColumn("last4DaysSum", coalesce($"last4DaysSum", lit(0)))
  .withColumn("last2DaysSum", coalesce($"last2DaysSum", lit(0)))
  .withColumn("prev2DaysSum", coalesce($"prev2DaysSum", lit(0)))
  .orderBy($"ID")
  .show()
```

Result:

```
+---+------------+------------+------------+
| ID|last2DaysSum|last4DaysSum|prev2DaysSum|
+---+------------+------------+------------+
|  1|           7|          10|           3|
|  2|           7|          18|          11|
|  3|           0|           0|           0|
+---+------------+------------+------------+
```

Note: I'm not sure if you meant prev2Days to be the previous 2 day interval before the current 2 day interval or the yesterday's last 2 day interval, because in the expected results table ID 1 has Oct. 11-12 summed and ID 2 has Oct. 10-11 summed for prev2Days, but either way you can adjust the range params if you want something else. I assumed that prev2Days does not overlap with last2Days, just change it to `sumLastNDays(now, 3, 1)` if you want overlapping 2 day ranges.

Comment: thank you for response. is that possible to use aggregation function to calculation the ratio of specific ID sum to a common group of IDs? for example I have a category with 10 different IDs. I need to calculate the ratio of a concrete ID sum to the entire Category sum in the defined range

Comment: If you only need one or a few specific IDs count ratio to group total you can use the same trick, `count(when($"ID" === lit(123), lit(1))) / count(lit(1))` if you need all ids then maybe you can do that with different window functions on the different counts in one aggregation and divide them by eachother, but I'm not sure of the top of my head.


If you only have one total count you need to divide with then you can calculate that and put it in a val and pass it in to divide by
val totalCount = data.count
data.groupBy($"ID").count.withColumn("ratio", $"count" / lit(totalCount))